# What is a good resource for objective data on what to label options in an application, e.g. should they be called settings, preferences, or options?

Tags: user-research, terminology, settings, options, preferences

I'm looking for objective and publicly available quantitative research on the language that users prefer or industry best practices on what to call options in an application.

When is it best to use settings vs preferences vs options vs etc.?

I read a previous question from 2012, but there were not any research sources, and I am looking for data to support one decision over the other.

[Options, preferences, settings, configurations: What to call them in my application?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/17442/options-preferences-settings-configurations-what-to-call-them-in-my-applicat/17890#17890)

Comment: "Preferences": Where there is no really *better* option (such as the colors). "Options": Changing it a lot. "Settings": Come in rarely.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a publicly available source for this information. It is normally derived from taxonomy research using a card sort methodology (this link explains more about this (please note this is a link to my agencies website. We are UX research experts): https://ux247.com/our-work/services/taxonomy/)

Although not designed for the purpose I have Google search results used as a measure of popularity where the subject could be isolated. Given the words you are considering are very common I don't think this would work for you so would suggest a quant card sort exercise.