# User menu, User's menu, User profile, User activity or something different for block of menu of the user?

Tags: menu, labels

When you log in on the site, you have in a sidebar a menu of a user (block; or widget if you are familiar with WordPress)  with links to his account settings, his comments, posts, private messages etc.

Which label for a heading would be grammatically more correct?

```
User menu
----------
-> settings
-> posts
-> messages
-> log out
```

or

```
User's menu
-----------
-> settings
-> posts
-> messages
-> log out
```

I have asked this question also on English subdomain of stackexchange, but they suggested this subdomain will be more appropriate.

They have proposed names like "User profile", "User Activity", but these do not sound good for a bigger group of menu links like user's posts, comments, profile, settings, friends, logout etc.

What do you think?

Comment: See http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/24612/my-account-or-your-account/24669

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it really need an explicit heading? I would instead reflect that member's identity (e.g. their name and photo) and use that as an implicit heading for those links.

Comment: Yes, because of the design of other bolcks in sidebar. Header is a must!

Comment: Perhaps "Your Account" or "Your [website name]", as well as showing the member name and such.

Comment: But it is a menu! Consider e.g. similar thing like "Admin Menu" vs "Admin Account". Admin account sounds like a role not like a menu.

Comment: But I'm not sure why you need to explicitly label a menu with the word "menu". Perhaps I'm missing something in the detail here.

Comment: E.g. I can say my customer: "In User menu on the right side of the page you will see many links. There you will need to click on "My settings", if you would like to go to your settings page.". My grammar is bad, but I think you get my point. For me... "User Account" sounds somehow abstract. In contrast "User Menu" is something more concrete and real. At least to me ;)

Comment: I see, but I think you're tying yourself in linguistic knots with little real benefit to the user. The important thing is that it's easily recognisable as a menu by virtue of its location and appearance and that the links it contains have clear and concise descriptions that make their targets clear. If the menu needs a heading at all, it should describe the purpose of the menu (to access stuff do to with the member’s account) rather than state its function as a “menu”.