# Username vs "My Library" for media collection menu bar link

Tags: website-design, usability, mobile, menu, terminology

My application has two libraries: a user's private library and the application's public library.  The user has no user profile, just a settings page and their library, listing the content they've created.

I'm trying to decide whether to use the user's username to link to My Library, or if I should have a dedicated My Library button and have the username link to the settings page, or maybe something else.

My thoughts:

It's good to know that **I** am logged in, so I'd prefer to have the username.  But it's not very clear that my username brings me to My Library... so I'm not sure what's best.

Comment: possible duplicate of ['My Account' or 'Your Account'?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/24612/my-account-or-your-account)

Answer (score 3):

It is a well-established pattern that clicking on your username will take you to your profile page where you can

- see and/or manage your profile;
- manage subscriptions, purchases and the like;
- change your password.

Violating this pattern will most likely frustrate your users. You should use clearly labeled ("My Library" and "Public Library" are pretty descriptive to start with!) navigation items.

Comment: What if the user's profile IS their private library, and password/email/etc are in a settings page?  There is no public user profile per se.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to explain that one. Maybe even edit your question, post screenshots and/or mockups?

Comment: Updated the original post

Answer (score 2):

Clicking username to take one to their library is not obvious and there's no established precedent for it. "username's Library" would be much clearer.  Alternatively, "Public Library" and "Private Library" (or "Personal Library") are also clear.

Answer (score 0):

User experience which formed for a years is username for a profile. As default settings satisfy the majority, profile link is not frequently visited. So placing My Library content under username brings bad UX.