# What are some analogs for "My Account"?

Tags: user-expectation, terminology

I'm working on a web application and I'm looking to name the area of the site that has the following:

- **Manager Profile** (preferences for the current user who is a manager. Like avatar, name, email, etc)
- **Company Profile** (preferences for the current user and others in their company, like the company mailing address)
- **Notifications** (alerts for the user)
- **Billing** (user payment history)
- **Security** (recent logins for the user)

I considered *Profiles* but that wouldn't be encompassing enough.  I could also call it *My Account* or *Your Account* but that may not reflect the company profile aspect.  I currently have it named *Settings*, though not sure that would encompass Billing and Security.  I also just want to have one button to get to this area.

Thoughts?

I've viewed [this](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1328/user-profile-my-account-or-just-settings) and [this](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/24612/my-account-or-your-account).

Given the current design, I don't think using just the name of the user can work (as it works on SO).

Answer (score 3):

**Just call it 'Account'**

The 'My' is part of the problem and is unnecessary.

As long as there are no other menu items that might distract a user looking for any of the contained categories, this is the most simple and clear option.

FWIW, the application I manage, I use the label 'Account & Finance' because we have a persona that, unlike all other users, only every uses the product for financial reporting.

Comment: I like that too because it's shorter.  Will see what the feedback is like.

Comment: Bear in mind that the only feedback here that means anything is the feedback you get from testing with representative users. Simple click testing. Show the menu and ask where they’d click to find stuff. Soliciting feedback from colleagues on topics like this is a waste of time, as they know about as much about how users will interpret language as you do. Take the minimal viable variation and test with some users.  If the meets your goals, that’s the right option.

Answer (score 2):

I think Preferences/Settings/Options fits the bill quite well. You're concerned about "Billing" and "Security"—speaking for myself:

- "Billing history" I would expect to find somewhere where I can edit my billing information. Is this where I would find billing settings as well?
- "Security"—same as with billing, I'd expect to find login history near my security settings

Now, this is just one opinion among many. The way to sort it out is to conduct qualitative user testing with people (let them pretend they're in a scenario where they'd use this feature and then see whether they go for the "Settings" button). You could also do A/B testing to see whether there's significantly more people accessing one of these sections if it's under "Settings" vs. "Account".

Comment: As for Billing History, no - we intentionally don't store payment methods or billing information.  Just payment history.

Comment: I like the answer by Tin Man and would suggest placing Billing History and Security in a separate area. ( Thanks to Alan for prompting me to reconsider my original answer. )